# Как установить "слушателя" на другой экран используя flipper?

Tags: java, android

В OnCreate создаю:

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
int layouts[] = new int[]{R.layout.scr1, R.layout.scr2, R.layout.scr3, R.layout.scr4};
for (int layout : layouts) flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
        flipper.setDisplayedChild(NumScr)
```

Создаю кнопки:

```
Button btnValue, btnFF;
//Кнопка на экране scr1
btnValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnValue);
//Кнопка на экране scr2
btnFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFF);
```

Прописываю "слушателя":

```
View.OnClickListener onclBtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnValue:{} break;
        case R.id.btnScrFF: {} break;
        default:break;
     }
btnValue.setOnClickListener(onclBtn);
```

При попытке создать

```
btnFF.setOnClickListener(onclBtn);
```

приложение вылетает.
Почему и как исправить? Ниже "кусок простыни" выделенный красным.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
 main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.ka_ba.Vin/com.example.ka_ba.Vin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         at com.example.ka_ba.Vin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: Стектрейс в студию

Comment: Приведите полный код метода `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Вы ищете кнопки в активити, тогда как они во флиппере. Т.е. ищите в нём.

```
Button btnValue, btnFF;
//Кнопка на экране scr1
btnValue = (Button) flipper.findViewById(R.id.btnValue);
//Кнопка на экране scr2
btnFF = (Button) flipper.findViewById(R.id.btnFF);
```

Comment: Не помогло. К тому же первая кнопка (на scr1) прекрасно работает.